# Style applied only occasionally

Tags: wpf, windows-7, prism

I have a project that defines a set of default styles for controls used throughout my application.  However, certain styles are not being applied consistently.  For example, a progress bar is initially rendered like this:

[image: A progress bar rendered incorrectly]

but later in the application, it renders correctly:

[image: A progress bar rendered correctly]

I'm using Microsoft Prism, if that makes a difference - the progress bar renders incorrectly when the control is initially navigated to, but corrects itself when it is navigated from and then navigated to again.

It's also strange that the style seems to be partially applied - the custom shape is always applied correctly, but the color is not.

I think I'm importing the resource dictionary in a standard way:

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
        <!-- other resource dictionaries here -->
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

Any ideas why some styles are being applied inconsistently?

**Edit:** I just caught it showing up in black-and-white!

[image]

Comment: Are all the above three progress bar snapshots from the same screen? Also I observe that the resources are defined within the `UserControl.Resources` and not in `Application.Resources`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Turns out the style I was using to theme my `ProgressBar` referenced a `DynamicResource` that wasn't defined.  Apparently this causes the unpredictable behavior I was experiencing.

As a side note, I had to import the `ResourceDictionary` that defined the `DynamicResource` I needed in my `App.xaml`, not just in the `UserControl` that uses the `ProgressBar`.